# Is there a memory efficient way to reset a data model in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory, garbage-collection

In the project I am currently working on we are running an angular app on an handheld scanner device (the model is a Motorola MC9200).

We are using a browser called Zetakey web browser to run the web app. This browser by default has javascript garbage collection turned off in order to maintain a reasonable response time.

We discovered that after about 1.5 hours of use the browser crashes because it is out of memory.

As part of our program we use a page refresh to clear all data during a sort of logout sequence.

I think that this is causing the browser to reallocate all the memory on the page and it does not appear to clear the old memory.

I was wondering if there is a simple way in angular or javascript to reset the data without explicitly running through and resetting each variable and property.

[Edited for grammar]

Update:

Zetakey has given us an early deployment of their next browser release where they just slow down the garbage collection cycle instead of killing it completely. It seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: In JS, the only way to release memory is through garbage collection. So if this browser releases memory when a variable is no longer bound then you would have to explicitly reset each variable.

Comment: Well, if there's no garbage collection at all then making an object unreachable will not help. Since you do not control memory allocation in JS, I'm not sure if your problem can be solved.

Comment: Can't you just enable the GC?

Comment: Are you sure it's data? An often occuring problem with "longer running applications" is that event handlers are not detached correctly and are kept as reference, hence never garbage collected. (i.o.w do you attach stuff you should detach/allow to be garbage collected in the $destroy?)

Comment: Where did you read that garbage collection is disabled? That really doesn't seem right. It's not a good way to improve response time, not to mention if there were no garbage collection I'd expect to be running into issues much sooner than 1.5 hours.
If it's really true that there is no garbage collection your only choice is to refresh the page.

Comment: There is an option to turn on garbage collection that I got by contacting  the Zetakey company but the website is very slow to respond with garbage collection turned on. (takes it about 1 sec to register a tap on the screen)

Comment: if you have no way of doing garbage collection, then you will need to be hyper-aware of every single binding in angular.  It will be very important for you to know when and how event watchers are created, and you'll have to monitor every single new client script to verify that no unintended bindings are created.  In short, there is no simple path here.

Comment: @OrangeKing89 - How do did you activate the option to turn on garbage collection?  I am currently facing the same issue of browser crashes after a couple of hours of app usage.

Comment: There is an option in the settings file. I have not worked with this platform in a few years so I don't remember what it was called.